# what if broswer does-not allow cookie

Tags: java, session, servlets, cookies

I am working on a web based application with JSP and servlets. I am using the Cookie class and response.getCookie method to set cookies in the browser. But I have a doubt as to how will the behavior be when the browser does-not allow cookies, through browser setting. In this case,  will the servlet code like getCookie throw any exception? How will be the behavior ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In this case, will the servlet code like getCookie throw any exception?

No. It will merely return `null`.

> How will be the behavior ?

Exactly the same as if the user had never visited your site before and directly opened that page.